# Cannot log in to Area 51 (so cannot ask this in its Discussion Zone)

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login, user-accounts

I have an Area 51 account<sup>1</sup>:

> [image: Screenshot of my user profile page on Area 51]

But I cannot log in:

> [image: Screenshot of login error page, which states "Unable to log in: No user found"]

The option to sign up does not work either:

> [image: Screenshot of different login error page, which states "Unable to log in: An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. this is our fault. details information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified."]

The option to join this community starts off okay and picks up my email (which I have not screen-shot) but then returns this:

> [image: Screenshot of StackExchange.com 404 page, with the URL "area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm"]

These related posts are all shown as "fixed" or "status-complete" so mine is apparently a new bug and not (as far as I can tell) a duplicate:

[Can't log in to Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210771/906208)

[Unable to log in to Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210811/906208)

[I cannot log in to Area 51 using Stack Exchange as OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305170/906208)

---

<sup>1</sup>My Area 51 account does not show in my profile page's Visible Communities:

> [image: Screenshot of the list of communities on my Law.SE profile page]

But, quite bizarrely, it *does* show when I select edit my Visible Communities:

> [image: Screenshot of the list of "visible communities" on my Law.SE user settings > hide communities page]

Comment: It's OK to come here to report this. Possible duplicate [Can't join Area 51 discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390072/289691) P.S. Instead of "MetaA51", the name is Discussion Zone. This distinction is important because Area 51 is not a community (there are no community moderators, among other limitations); it's something unique that is reusing some stuff used for per-site-metas.

Comment: I've been having the same issue! I contacted support a few days ago (no response), and pestered Adam Lear about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335661/unable-to-login-area51-for-more-than-a-year/335761#comment1306048_335761) (see linked question for related discussion, it's possible the same thing's happening to you)

Comment: Yeah, like 130 years old human being, 15 year old software is also bound to fall apart, no matter how good it used to be. SE the company never gave any attention to Area 51, and we see the results of their ignorance now. (Not a single real update in all those years, just minor patching when they really had to.)

Comment: The "Log in" and "Sign up" buttons under the login error message (as shown in [Can’t login to Area 51 ( Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No user found)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324798)) aren't even there anymore :(

Comment: Also interesting, your A51 profile [_doesn't_ show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoUIT.png) on [your Network profile account list](https://stackexchange.com/users/19819548/rick?tab=accounts).

Comment: @zcoop98: I think you may have found the source of the problem: [their Area 51 Discussions profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/211087/rick) isn't properly mapped to their network account. Not sure why that is, but I suspect it's the cause of the issue.

Comment: @V2Blast I have the same issue. I can login on the Discussions page but not on Area 51 itself

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine: I'd suggest using the [Contact](/contact) form to report the issue, and then we can figure out what the problem is in your case. (It's not a matter of [your Area 51 Discussions profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/222536/insertcheesyline) not being properly mapped to your [network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/15692921/insertcheesyline), so it's not the same cause.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your patience. As V2Blast mentioned in the comments, somehow your A51 and A51 Discuss profiles weren't correctly mapped to your network account. I have a couple theories on why that I'm planning to investigate, but in the meantime, you should be all set.

Please let me know if you're still seeing any login issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in and all is good (apart from the proposal I wanted to support being closed in the meantime. *C'est la vie*)